# how to make text in the center

Tags: css

hello i am make like this example which i get from www.xxxxxx.com

http://s1172.photobucket.com/albums/r568/novikoraharja/?action=view&current=justanimage.png

i wanted too learn that so can you help me?

```
<div class="panjang">
    <ul>

        <li class="bungkus">

            <div class="kiri"><img src="http://i1172.photobucket.com/albums/r568/novikoraharja/3.jpg"/> </div>
            <div class="kanan">Very loooooong </div>
        </li>

        <li class="bungkus">
            <div class="kiri"><img src="http://i1172.photobucket.com/albums/r568/novikoraharja/3.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="kanan">Very loooooong text sooo lonngg </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

here the style

```
.panjang{width:400px;height;100px;}

.bungkus{width:200px; height:50px; background:yellow;}
.bungkus img { width:60px; height:40px; margin:5px 10px;}

.kiri { float:left; background:red; width:80px; height:50px; }
.kanan{vertical-align:middle; background:cyan; float:left;width:120px;height:50px;font-size:12px;vertical-align:middle;
}
```

here my works http://jsfiddle.net/76E4w/11/

i already add line-align:middle; or line weight but not work;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[See working jsFiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/K8349/)***

Add `display: table;` to `.bungkus`.

Remove `float: left;` from `.kanan`.

Add `display: table-cell;` to `.kanan`.

Comment: many thank buddy. just you open and see picture i post above and not even give me critic

Answer (score 2):

When you find a web site doing it as you like,
the easiest thing is to run **firefox** with **firebug**
and to look which css applies.

centering could be done in different ways.
one is

```
text-align: center
```

An other approach is to set right/left margin to auto

```
margin: 0 auto;
```